# Concurrent requests to Stanford CoreNLP server don't scale

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am running the local Stanford CoreNLP server and I am trying to simulate the load by creating simultaneous POST requests. I noticed that the processing time increases linearly with the number of "users" that send requests to the server. The `threads` option is set to 8. Am I missing something? I feel like going from 1 user/process to 2 should not have such an impact...

Stanford CoreNLP with this command:

`nohup java -mx10g -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=error -cp "${USER_HOME}/stanford-corenlp/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -threads 8 -serverProperties "${USER_HOME}/NLP/dependencyparser/dependencyparser/tools.properties" -port 9000 -timeout 300000 -preload  > ${USER_HOME}/log/StanfordCoreNLPServer.log 2>&1 & disown`

To simulate simultaneous requests I am using `multiprocessing` in python to send requests asynchronously. Each process will send the same request 5 times.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import time

def send_stanford_request(batch_id):
    all_data = ['This is sample Sentence 1. \nThis is sample Sentence 2. \nThis is sample Sentence 3']

    num_requests=5

    t0 = time.time()

    for ii in range(num_requests):
        rr = requests.post('http://[::]:9000/?properties={"outputFormat":"text"}', all_data)

    t1 = time.time()
    time_batch = t1 - t0

    out_res = {'batch_id':batch_id,'total_batch_time':time_batch,
               'batch_time_per_req':time_batch/num_requests}
    return out_res
```

Here I create multiple processes that send requests at the same time:

```
def multi_requests(nprocs):
    tt0 = time.time()

    process = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nprocs)
    out_data = process.map(send_stanford_request,list(range(1,nprocs+1)))
    process.close()    

    tt1 = time.time()

    full_run_time = tt1-tt0

    print ("Processing complete with {} processes".format(nprocs))
    print ("Total time: {}".format((tt1-tt0)))
    return out_data,full_run_time
```

The main program:

```
if __name__=="__main__":

    total_time_list = []
    for nreq in range(1,11,1):
        out_nreq,full_run_time = multi_requests(nreq)
        total_time_list.append(full_run_time)

    print(total_time_list)
```

Output:

```
[25.180917024612427, 50.08782601356506, 75.14966297149658, 
100.1421709060669, 125.16093802452087, 150.2395520210266, 
175.24192595481873, 200.2490758895874, 225.28618001937866, 
250.2914171218872]
```

Properies file:

```
annotators = tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,dcoref
depparse.extradependencies = MAXIMAL
depparse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_SD.gz
outputExtension = .out
parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz
ssplit.eolonly = true
ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak = always
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the same result when I do this:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

from stanza.server import CoreNLPClient

filename="1000.txt"

lines = open(filename).readlines()

def annotate(batch_id):
    with CoreNLPClient(annotators=['tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','depparse','ner'],
                       start_server=False,
                       timeout=60000) as client:
        # submit the request to the server
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            ann = client.annotate(line)

def multi_requests(nprocs):
    tt0 = time.time()

    process = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nprocs)
    out_data = process.map(annotate,list(range(1,nprocs+1)))
    process.close()

    tt1 = time.time()

    full_run_time = tt1-tt0

    print ("Processing complete with {} processes".format(nprocs))
    print ("Total time: {}".format((tt1-tt0)))
    return out_data,full_run_time

for i in range(5):
    multi_requests(i+1)
```

I started my server locally with this:

`java -Xmx5G edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 60000 -threads 5 -maxCharLength 100000 -quiet True -preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,ner,depparse -parse.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz`

This is the timing information I get:

```
Processing complete with 1 processes
Total time: 57.21682000160217
Processing complete with 2 processes
Total time: 61.54398465156555
Processing complete with 3 processes
Total time: 68.56325793266296
Processing complete with 4 processes
Total time: 77.91925978660583
Processing complete with 5 processes
Total time: 86.51665258407593
```

The server is going to get a little slower when there are multiple requests.  Certainly not 5x, though.

When I ran your code, I got:

```
Processing complete with 1 processes
Total time: 0.362884521484375
Processing complete with 2 processes
Total time: 0.40112733840942383
Processing complete with 3 processes
Total time: 0.4257957935333252
Processing complete with 4 processes
Total time: 0.4603590965270996
Processing complete with 5 processes
Total time: 0.4904172420501709
```

I don't know how you got 25s per thread when running 3 short sentences worth of text.